# how i can save my data file to my webspace through my iphone app

Tags: iphone

I want to save the data which i gather through my iphone app to my webspace in xml format so that the other user's can access it and see the data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTTP client library such as ASIHTTPRequest or HTTPRiot. Issue a POST request to a resource on your server, with the XML included in the request body.

Comment: What do you mean by "POST request to a resource on your server" what does server means?? Do you mean provider or do ihave to make my own server.

Comment: Yes, your website will have to handle the request and save it.

Comment: @UltimateBrent: Can you give me some link which explains this. I have never done this knid of stuff.

Comment: This is probably beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question. But take hope: If you can write an iPhone app, you can figure out how the web works.

Comment: Yep, web programming is significantly easier than Objective-C. Get a book on PHP or something and learn the basics. Won't take you long.

Comment: Ashutosh, UltimateBrent is joking about the PHP part.